# How to add percentages to an output

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I would like to add a relative percentage to an SQL output

Here is the code:

```
SELECT customer_status.status AS "Status of Customer",         
       COUNT (customer_bio),     
FROM customer_status     
JOIN customer_bio     
  ON customer_status.status_id=customer_bio.status_id     
GROUP BY status
```

Here is the output

| Status | Number |
| --- | --- |
| Switched Off | 352 |
| Out of Town | 743 |
| Not reachable | 564 |
| Active | 13738 |
| Relocated | 78 |

I want to add percentage on another column where by switched off is 352/total number * 100

I tried this:

```
SELECT customer_status.status AS "Status of Customer",
       count(customer_bio)
       count(customer_bio)/count(*) * 100 AS "Percentage
FROM customer_status
JOIN customer_bio
  ON customer_status.status_id=customer_bio.status_id
GROUP BY status
```

|nd this is what I get:

| Status | Number | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Switched Off | 352 | 100 |
| Out of Town | 743 | 100 |
| Not reachable | 564 | 100 |
| Active | 13738 | 100 |
| Relocated | 78 | 100 |

Please assist. I use postgresql via azure data studio

Answer (score 1):

Both `COUNT(customer_bio)` and `COUNT(*)` give you the same output because they're both aggregated on the same partition (`GROUP BY status`).

You can try using window functions instead. Since window functions compute values for each record, you can then remove duplicate rows with the `DISTINCT` operator.

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_status.status AS "Status of Customer",
                COUNT(customer_bio) OVER(w)
                COUNT(customer_bio) OVER(w) / COUNT(customer_bio) OVER() * 100 AS "Percentage
FROM       customer_status
INNER JOIN customer_bio
        ON customer_status.status_id=customer_bio.status_id
GROUP BY status
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY status)
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this way:

```
declare @total_count as real

select @total_count =count(*) from customer_bio

SELECT customer_status.[status] AS 'Status of Customer',
       count(customer_bio),
       count(customer_bio)/@total_count * 100 AS 'Percentage'
FROM customer_status
JOIN customer_bio
  ON customer_status.status_id=customer_bio.status_id
GROUP BY [status]
```